# Como ingresar la fecha actual en un Query con PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

quisiera saber la forma de mandar a la base de datos la fecha actual en la que se ejecuta el query, para eso tengo este codigo por ahora:

```
$product_id = $conexion->real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
        $product = $conexion->real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
        $pst = pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO reports (user_id, product_id, date, estado) VALUES ('$user','$product_id','',1)");
```

Como veis, en la sentencia me hace falta el espacio "date" luego de "product_id" quisiera saber como hacer para ingresar la fecha actual ahí, muchas gracias de ante mano

 Phpmyadmin

Comment: ¿Sólo la fecha o fecha y hora?

Comment: Si es posible, ambas estaría bien

Comment: usa la función now()

Comment: Ehh, pero se guarda en una variable o como funciona?

Comment: Como dice @BetaM NOW() te devuelve la fecha y hora del momento en que se ejecuta, no se guarda en una variable a menos que tu lo quieras, un ejemplo podría ser: select NOW();

Comment: Coloqué esto: $pst = pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO reports (user_id, product_id, date, estado) VALUES ('$user','$product_id', now(),1)"); --- Y me salta este error syntax error, unexpected '-&gt;' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)